# Prove that If A is minimal Grill, then A is maximal Filter.

Tags: general-topology, filters

**Prove:**

$A$ is a minimal Grill $\implies$ $A$ is a maximal Filter.

**Attempt:**

$A$ is Grill $\implies sec(A)$ is Filter.

$A$ is a minimal Grill $\implies$ ($\forall G, G-$  Grill: $A \subset G$) $\implies$ $\forall G, G-Grill: sec(G) \subset sec(A)$, here $sec(G)$ and $sec(A)$ are both Filter.

I am stuck at trying to prove: $sec(A) = A$, which would be the last step.

Comment: It seems you're following Herrlich's book? Define "sec" and grill, for those who don't have it, please!

Comment: Well,I just did that myself, you might want to check whether you agree with my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, we should know that

- $\mathcal{A}$ a grill implies $\operatorname{sec}(\mathcal{A})$ is a filter.
- $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B} \implies  \operatorname{sec}(\mathcal{B}) \subseteq \operatorname{sec}(\mathcal{A})$
- $\mathcal{A}$ is a filter implies that $\operatorname{sec}(\mathcal{A})$ is a grill.
- $\operatorname{sec}(\operatorname{sec}(\mathcal{A}))=\mathcal{A}$ for either filters or grills $\mathcal{A}$.

So $\text{sec}$ is a self-inverse order reversing map from grills to filters and back. This implies that minimal elements in one set are mapped to maximal ones in the other.

For the benefit of other readers: a filter is the usual non-empty family of non-empty subsets (we are working in some universe $X$) that is closed under binary intersections and supersets, while a grill is a non-empty family of non-empty subsets closed under supersets and obeying $$\forall A,B \subseteq X: (A \cup B) \in \mathcal{A} \implies A \in \mathcal{A} \text{ or } B \in \mathcal{A}$$

while for a family of subsets $\mathcal{A}$ we define

$$\operatorname{sec}(\mathcal{A}) = \{B \subseteq X\mid \forall A \in \mathcal{A}: B \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$$

(This is from the duality convergence theory section in Herrlich's book "Topologie I, Topologische Räume", at least that's where I first saw it.)

Comment: Those definitions are correct. I've seen them in a script but they might just originally come from that book.

Comment: @СССР you probably mean “lecture notes” instead of script. Probably by someone influenced by said book. Your teacher’s German perhaps?

Comment: That is correct, I study M.Sc. Math at a German University.

Comment: I first saw "grill" (or rather the French "grille") in Berge's book "Espaces topologiques: fonctions multivoques" when I was a student. In recent times, I've seen these called "coideals" (because they're the complements of the ideals dual to filters) and "partition regular families" (because any partition of a set in a grill into finitely many pieces has a piece in the grill). Now that I know that "grill" isn't just Berge's term, I'll feel free to use it instead of the longer names.  Thanks for the Herrlich pointer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass In his textbook that I mentioned he doesn’t give any reference for the use of that term ( in German), I don’t have an English translation of that text. It’s the only place I’ve ever seen it used, funny that you have a French connection.